# Extruding Faces, uv messes up

Tags: uv, extrude

So I have a uv,unwrapped cube, but when I use the extrude tool to make part of it stick out, the sides of the extruded segment have different uv wrapping, which causes issues:

[image]

It looks like that because those sides are exactly between a red and transparent pixel. Is there any way to fix this? I need to extrude about 120 of these faces.

Comment: What I see there is overlapping (duplicated) faces, creating Z -fighting. In edit mode press Ctrl+V and select **Remove Doubles**. Also as workflow is better to edit the object first, and then UV unwrap, as modifications on the geometry will affect the UV mapping.

Comment: There are no doubles there, actually. What's happening is the side faces of the extrusion have a uv map where it is directly between a red and transparent pixel. I want to extrude so that the side faces don't have a different uv map placement than the face im extruding from (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 3):

If you are extruding along an orthagonal direction, you can press `e` to start extruding and then press `g g` (`g` twice) to continue extruding the edge while automatically updating the UV coordinates for the extruded face(s).

[image: Extruding with 'e' followed by 'gg']